# terraform modules Error: Reference to undeclared module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-modules

Please help me with terraform on GCP, i already some days banging my head against the wall. Who have good exp with terraform, you take this 5 mins.

all needed  files is uploaded,  it is include 2 modules, first (create google project) is static - which downloaded from terraform tegistry it uses when terraform init run ,  and second (create vm in new created google project) - which already  created.  Error file is also uploaded. PLEASE GIVE ADVICE!

1 module is  called project - is worked well, it is create new project and generate in ourput project_id

it use this module -  https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google/5.0.0

2 module is called redis_vm-  have to use this project_id  (output from module 1) and create new mv and some other thinks, like network and firewall rules.

And main - why from module 2 input - it is not see output from module 1 ?  I try everything.  But always get something like that

**Error: Reference to undeclared module
on modules/redis_vm/main.tf line 13, in resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network":
  13:   project = "${module.project.project_id}"
No module call named "project" is declared in redis_vm.**

for example if I use in module 2

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "${var.name}"
  machine_type = "${var.machine_type}"
  project     =  "${module.project.project_id}"  # - IT IS NOW LOOKING FOR THIS - IT IS OUTPUT FROM MODULE 1
```

link to files here
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_s9yuKQ3Prn-9CLsRcovjxes--FW2lcZ?usp=sharing

Thanks for helping.‹ collapse